# My label is not counting up

Tags: javascript, html

Why is this code not working? So far I have only got it to work as an input. I need it to work as a label or span. I need the label to count up 1 number on every click.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = 1;

        function increase () {
            document.getElementById("text").value=a;
            a=a+1;
        }            
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="increase()">show</button>
    <label type="text" id="text">0</label>
</body>
```

​

Comment: Please describe more in detail what you want to achieve. Should this count up at every page load? Or button click? Anyway, you don't write the result in `a` back to the label element.

Comment: See edited post. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/90vndvph/)

i have tried `parseInt()`

```
 var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("text").innerHTML);

 a++;
 console.log(a);
 document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = a;
```

Answer (score 6):

Your `increase()` function should look like this:

```
function increase() {
    a++;
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = a;
}
```

The reason its not working is that `label` or `span` doesn't have `value` attribute. You should use `innerHTML` instead.

`Value` attribute is present only on `<input>` tags. For every other tag (like `<span>`, `<div>`, `<label>`) you should use `innerHTML`.

---

### Edit

To add clarity, the above code is only the `increment()` function. The entire code should look like this:

```
var a = 0;

function increase() {
    a++;
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = a;
}
```

Considering John Hascall comment, `a++` can be placed after `document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = a`.

```js
var a = 0;

function increase() {
  a++;
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = a;  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="increase()">Click</button>
<label id="text">0</label>
```

Comment: Actually, it looks like he would want to either do those in the other order or start out with `var a = 0;`

Comment: @some-non-descript-user he already has a variable tracking the label's value.  But yes, an *alternative* would be to not have the variable and fetch the innerHTML first.

Comment: `document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = ++a;`

Comment: @crl I thought that it would be too obfuscated for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=a`, because the value of a `<label>` does not define its inside text.

Your example would then look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        var a = 1;          

        function increase() {
            a++;
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = a;                 
        }            
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="increase()">show</button>
    <label type="text" id="text">0</label>
</body>
```